# JavaScript commas and dots when returning more than 3 figure values

Tags: javascript, replace, floating-point

I have a function which calculates price discount and then returns a new value. Since the base value is string, I need to convert it into float, and then work with it.

The problem is that numbers with 4 figures (1000) or more are written with comma and dot, for instance:
1.000,99

and with this numbers I have problem since the function turns it into float number and fixed to 2 decimals, and at the end I get 1.00 instead of 1.000,99

Here is the function:

```
    if(saisonOne()){
              //Saison 1 +  

   var rabat1 = parseFloat(0.15);


    sumOffer1 = parseFloat(sumOffer.replace(',', '.') )*rabat1;  

    sumOffer2 = parseFloat(sumOffer.replace(',', '.')) - sumOffer1; 

    sumOffer = sumOffer2.toFixed(2).replace('.', ',') + " p€"; 

    console.log(sumOffer);

//Saison 2

} else if (saisonTwo()){
```

Thanks in advance!
Denis

Answer (score 0):

First you have to replace the German currency notation to the JS standard. In general one might do that as follows;

```js
var dePrice = "1.000.000,99",
    usPrice = dePrice.replace(/(\.)|(\,)/g,(m,p1,p2) => p1 ? p1 = "," : p2 = ".");
console.log(usPrice);
```

But in your case we don't want the thousands separator commas so that we can convert it into Number. Then we replace the `","` in our replacer callback function with `""` and type coerce the resulting string into number by a preceeding `+`.

```js
var price = "1.000.000,99",
    value = +price.replace(/(\.)|(\,)/g,(m,p1,p2) => p1 ? p1 = "" : p2 = ".");
console.log(value);
```